# Email PDF attachment content missing image

Tags: node.js, email, gmail-api

I call Gmail API using a nodejs script using the request library (not the google one).
When I write the attachment response into a pdf file, I can see that the content is incomplete (missing images, missing styles, etc...).

Code:

```js
const attachment: IGoogleMailUserMessageAttachmentResource = await this.call(
    'GET',
    `/${message.id}/attachments/${part.body.attachmentId}`,
);

writeFileSync('/tmp/test.pdf', attachment.content, { flag: 'w+' });
```

Received file :

[image]

instead of :

[image]

Any idea ?

Thanks